# Authenticate and Authorize all microsoft accounts including personal account and other tenants

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

I am new to Authentication and tried to follow many Microsoft forums for setting up authentication and authorization for my Angular front end + .Net core API but could not complete it successfully.

So far I am able to authenticate only Microsoft tenant users.

Below is my MSAL config on Angular side for front end authentication.

All my app registrations are supported for 'All Microsoft account users' i.e. including Microsoft personal account like hotmail,live etc.

```
export const authConfig={
clientId: 'd10e4d98-e7c57151bcf1-**',
authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/',
redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
graphEndpoint:'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',
consentScopes: [
'api://fd51sdf-e4sdf-4e07-9dc9-/MyAppName.ReadAll'
],
}
```

Below code is on API side startup class

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
.AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureActiveDirectory", options));
```

AppSettings Config:

```
"AzureActiveDirectory": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"SubscriptionId": "",
"TenantId": "common",
"ClientId": "api://fd51sdf-e4sdf-4e07-9dc9-",
"ClientSecret": "arMTdfdfdwZTf"
}
```

The issue I am getting with this config is, After I login with my personal hotmail account I am getting 401 Unauthorized for all API calls irrespective of role. Below is the error.

> Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience
> 'api://fd51sdf-e4sdf-4e07-9dc9-' is invalid"

Could you please let me know if there is any problem with configuration.

Comment: After decoding the token , if you have v2 endpoint in 'iss' i.e issuer then in app manifest , accesstokenacceptedversion must be changed to 2 and make sure you check marked access token.Try that. If that doesn't work remove api:// prefix from client id in appsetting and try.

Comment: Does kavyasaraboju-MT's comment useful to you ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have checked it and my app registration shows as below.

"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"

I have tried by removing prefix api:// as well but api is not authorizing the request and showing the same error.

Is it possible to have a quick conversation and show you my code? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: The thing is that "aud" claim must match the audience which is nothing but the client id.So it mostly depends on already given point.It seems your consent scopes i.e ; api://clientid/MyAppName.ReadAll >in this client id has extra * at last but in app settings client id doesn't have that. Please make sure your client ids are correctly configured in both front end and backend .Also please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65143355/how-to-configure-net-core-angular-azure-ad-authentication).This is what all i can suggest as per my knowledge. (direct conversation is not possible)

Comment: Hi Kavya, For privacy purpose I have trimmed some part of the app id and added * marks at the end of the application id. I have corrected it now. Please check.

Comment: @kavyasaraboju-MT  What's interesting is that according to op said, the error only occurs on personal accounts, and work accounts can work very well.